# Problems with .NET Remoting TransparentProxy

Tags: .net, remoting, appdomain

I'm trying to execute some code in AppDomain using Reflection.
Here is my code:

```
AppDomain appDomain = GetSomehowAppDomain(); 
string typeAssembly = GetTypeAssembly();
string typeName = GetTypeName();
object targetObject = appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeAssembly, typeName);
MethodInfo methodInfo = targetObject.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);
object result = methodInfo.Invoke(targetObject, methodParams);
```

When this code is running under web site everything is OK. 
But when I'm doing this from console application which calls WCF service which tries to call the above code - `methodInfo` is `null` and I'm getting `NullReferenceException` at last line.

By the way `targetObject` is of `System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy` type and I assumed that if it proxy in GoF pattern meaning I can access members of type which is original source for proxing. But `targetObject` doesn't have members of `typeName` type.

Using `targetObject.GetType().GetMethods()` I've found out that it has 7 methods:

1. GetLifetimeService
2. InitializeLifetimeService
3. CreateObjRef
4. ToString
5. Equals
6. GetHashCode
7. GetType

`targetObject` is expected to be a proxy for `WorkflowManager` type.

`public class WorkflowsManager : MarshalByRefObject, ISerializable, IDisposable, IWorkflowManager`

Comment: Could you also add some snippets of code from the `targetObject` class definition or is that irrelevant?

Comment: Is your `targetObject` class derived from `ContextBoundObject`?

Comment: If you change the definition to: `[ServiceContract] public class WorkflowsManager : ContextBoundObject, IDisposable, IWorkflowManager`, what happens?

Comment: Nothing changed. And `targetObject.GetType()` still returns `MarshalByRefObject` not `ContextBoundObject`.

Comment: What does `System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.GetRealProxy(targetObject)` return?

Comment: It returns instance of `System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy`. What parameters are you interested in?

Comment: Another interesting point is: you should see at least two more methods  - `Dispose()` and `GetObjectData()`, as you implement `IDisposable` and `ISerializable`.

Comment: `System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.GetRealProxy(targetObject).GetProxiedType();`

Comment: Should but actually can't see :(
If to dig into internals of `targetObject` under debug. I'm able to see that `targetObject._rp.IdentityObject._obj.Ref.TypeInfo.interfacesImplemented` contains all three interfaces `ISerializable`, `IDisposable`, `IWorkflowManager`.

Comment: `GetProxiedType` returns `MarshalByRefObject`.

Comment: Sorry, can't connect to chat from this location... What is the value of `targetObject.GetType().Assembly`?

Comment: mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

Comment: This is not the expected return value, it should be the fully qualified assembly name of your `WorkflowsManager` class' assembly.

Comment: Yes, it would be nice :) But...

Comment: Have you tried casting the unwrapped object to it's type? Is this working? `WorkflowsManager targetObject = (WorkflowsManager)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeAssembly, typeName);`

Comment: No, I haven't tried that because methods are invoked via reflection (this is our custom infrastructure code, `WorkflowManager` is at higher layer and is not available here at compile time, its assembly is loading in `AppDomain` at runtime.

Comment: Maybe you should focus on the logic in the `GetSomehowAppDomain` method. I'll post an answer with a code sample which works for me.

Comment: @AlexK Why don't you add more code? Add the code of the WCF service and the configuration so we can test it.

Comment: Do you have any update on this? I experience the same issue (targetObject.GetType().GetMethods() return those of MarshalByRefObject, not any of the actual type). Casting as the underlying type returns null.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Panos Rontogiannis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850119/panos-rontogiannis)'s comment, I realized that I was missing the indication from your question that you actually load the assembly in your WCF code, not in the console application.

Make sure that the actual assembly version from the GAC is the one which your are expecting to work with in your WCF code.

I've updated the solution which resembles your scenario.

```
//After building the library, add it to the GAC using "gacutil -i MyLibrary.dll"
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace MyLibrary
{
    [Serializable]
    public class MyClass : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public string Work(string name)
        {
            return String.Format("{0} cleans the dishes", name);
        }
    }
}
```

The service class definition in the web application:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public class MyService : IMyService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        public string DoWork(string name)
        {
            string methodName = "Work";
            object[] methodParams = new object[] { "Alex" };
            AppDomain appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("");
            appDomain.Load("MyLibrary, Version=1.0.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a6d06b33e075e91");
            string typeAssembly = "MyLibrary, Version=1.0.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a6d06b33e075e91";
            string typeName = "MyLibrary.MyClass";
            object targetObject = appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeAssembly, typeName);
            MethodInfo methodInfo = targetObject.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);
            string result = methodInfo.Invoke(targetObject, methodParams).ToString();
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

The console application which calls the WCF service:

```
using System;
using WebApplication1;

namespace ConsoleApplication12
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebApplication1.MyService myService = new MyService();
            Console.WriteLine(myService.DoWork("Alex"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the code you have added in Main to be executed from within the WCF service.

Comment: Thanks @PanosRontogiannis, I was totally missing it.

Comment: I don't place assemblies to GAC. `GetSomehowAppDomain();` loads assemblies to newly created `AppDomain` by itself from well-known place.